# Python Regex either or case

Tags: python, regex, nltk, lemmatization

I have a small module that gets the lemma of a word and its plural form. It then searches through sentences looking for a sentence that contains both words (singular or plural) in either order. I have it working but i was wondering if there is a **more elegant** way to build this expression. Thanks! 
Note: Python2

```
words = ((cell,), (wolf,wolves))
string1 = "(?:"+"|".join(words[0])+")"
string2 = "(?:"+"|".join(words[1])+")"
pat = ".+".join((string1, string2)) +"|"+ ".+".join((string2, string1))
# Pat output: "(?:cell).+(?:wolf|wolves)|(?:wolf|wolves).+(?:cell)"
```

Then the search:

```
pat = re.compile(pat)
for sentence in sentences:
    if len(pat.findall(sentence)) != 0:
        print sentence+'\n'
```

Comment: is performance an issue?  Or are you just looking for a code review?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a codereview. It should be moved to [codereview.stackoverflow.com](http://codereview.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Performance is the main concern, yes.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
[ x for x in sentences if re.search( '\bcell\b', x ) and
        ( re.search( '\bwolf\b', x ) or re.search( '\bwolves\b', x ) )]
```

Comment: It seems like running 3 seperate re.search() calls will only hurt performance. This module will be used on thousands of sentences at a time so speed is a huge issue.

Comment: @JesseTravis you are using `findall` which does __not__ stop at first match, also the pattern is much more complicated. with the above version it will stop if it cannot find any `\bcell\b`, and will not run any of the two other regular expressions

Comment: I'll look in to this. I think it needs to be re.search('\bcell', x) to catch the plural 'cells' as well though.

Comment: I ran a few tests on a 1m file and my method is still slightly quicker than the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you start adding multiple compound look-around expressions, your algorithmic complexity gets out of control.  This is going to be a fundamental problem with using regex to solve this problem.

An alternate approach is to try making one O(n) pass per sentence with a `Counter` and then querying against that:

```
#helper function
def count_lemma(counter,*args):
    return sum(counter[word] for word in args)

from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

for sentence in sentences:
    c = Counter(x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for x in sentence.split())
    if all(count_lemma(c,*word) for word in words):
        print sentence
```